# Convert JSON string to object C#

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON string results as follows.
[image]

In this response Sometimes sizeKey and sizeName properties are returned as a string. But sometimes both properties are returns inside an array as follows
[image]

I am using following code to convert it to object

```
var assets = jObject["assets"].Children().ToList();
            foreach (var item in assets)
            {
                decorationAssets.Add(item.ToObject<AEDecorationAssets>());
            }
```

And my AEDecorationAssets class is as follows.

```
public class AEDecorationAssets
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string[] Colors { get; set; }
    public string FontKey { get; set; }
    public string SizeKey { get; set; }
    public string ViewKey { get; set; }
    public string FontName { get; set; }
    public int Rotation { get; set; }
    public string SizeName { get; set; }
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string TextEffectKey { get; set; }
    public string TextEffectName { get; set; }
    public string DecorationMethod { get; set; }
    public string NumDecorationColors { get; set; }
}
```

At the time when "sizeKey" is an array, the above code gives an error. How can I resolve this issue? Is there any JSON property we can use to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried with `public List<string> SizeKey { get; set; }`

Comment: It's a backend mistake. API is not in proper state

Comment: it's not only about the SizeKey property. When result in an array SizeKey and the SizeName both properties inside the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do it is by making your `SizeKey` type an `object` (i.e.     `public object SizeKey { get; set; }`), then you can switch/case on `item.ToObject<AEDecorationAssets>().SizeKey.GetType()` to figure out how to handle it (i.e. if `String` do this, if `JArray` do that), etc.

Comment: If(item.ToObject<AEDecorationAssets>().SizeKey.GetType() == typeof(JArray)){((JArray)SizeKey).ToObject<List<CustomObject>>();}

Comment: @udaya726 don't forget your null checks!

Answer (score 0):

If a JSON type is sometime an `array`, and sometimes a `string`, you can't really map it simply to a .NET type, as there is none that supports this behavior.

So first you need a datatype that can store this, like and `string[]` or `List<string>`.

It could be that `JsonConvert` will solve this automatically, but otherwise you'll need to write a custom `ContractResolver` or `JsonConverter`. Here you can detect if the source property is a string or array. If it's an `array`, you can use the default deserialization. If it is a `string`, you need to convert it to an array with a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get json result for which you want to create c# object and then you can valid json response from https://jsonlint.com/ and then you can create c# object of any type json response which you want through http://json2csharp.com. And after get c# object of your json response you only need to deserialization of your json response to c# object which you have created. which will return you expected result.